# In NixOS, is there a way to use Rofi instead of Dmenu when invoking Passmenu?

Tags: nixos, dmenu, rofi

I'm using the `pass` package for password management. The `passmenu` command that comes with it uses `dmenu`, but I'd like for it to use Rofi instead. I saw [on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rofi#Rofi_as_dmenu_replacement) that it's possible to use rofi as a drop-in dmenu replacement, but the path structures of NixOS are so complex that I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Should I create a new package for it? Or is there a way to update [the original pass package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/tools/security/pass/default.nix) so that it uses rofi instead?

Comment: Firstly, have you tried rofi-pass (https://github.com/carnager/rofi-pass)? There's a Nix package for it. As for your question, the passmenu package takes dmenu as an optional argument. So, you can override the passmenu package to accept an alternative "dmenu" package. rofi takes on dmenu functionality when it's called via a symbolic link named dmenu, so you may be able to get away with a tiny dmenu-emulation package which simply symlinks to rofi. Then, you'd provide said package when overriding passmenu.

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

For Arch there is a package in the AUR that symlinks `dmenu` to `rofi`. That makes the regular `passmenu` work with `rofi` instead: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rofi-dmenu

You could do the same yourself:

```bsh
ln -s /usr/bin/rofi /usr/bin/dmenu
```